# Information about JCS

Tags: java, caching, jcs

This is conjunction with my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428911/jcs-disk-cache-data-retrieval

Does JCS read from disk even after the application is shutdown.i.e I have a JCS that writes to disk.The thing is one program does the caching that is writing to disk and another one reads from the disk.I run the writing program at one time and after a few minutes the read program is run.But when the read program is run,it comes up with null data even though the write program has successfully written to disk.Do caching systems work like this.Does it just use the disk for temporary storage,even though the cache writes the objects to disk.Does the information on the disk become invalid after application shutdown or restart.
I want to know whether JCS with respect to the disk part works like a storage system.

Comment: Don't phrase a question as if it's about "caching systems in general" when you're really asking about a specific implementation. The answer depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your cache.ccf file, add an option
jcs.region.YOUR_CACHE_NAME.cacheattributes.DiskUsagePatternName=UPDATE
Read [this](http://commons.apache.org/jcs/RegionProperties.html). Especially about DiskUsagePatternName.

```
JCS cache = JCS.getInstance("calcCache");
cache.put("keeeeeeeeeey", "vaaaaaaaalue");
```

This simple example works normally.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but how do I read it back.Still that null data error is only coming.

Comment: I had the same issue and this helped me.Are you sure that you've added option on the right place? I can send content of my cache.ccf file if you want.

Comment: Yes.I am quite sure.but anyway send the cache.ccf file,it will anyways be helpful.Thanks

Comment: ##############################################################
##### CACHE REGIONS
jcs.region.calcCache=DC
jcs.region.calcCache.cacheattributes=org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes
jcs.region.calcCache.cacheattributes.MaxObjects=1000
jcs.region.calcCache.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName=org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache
jcs.region.calcCache.cacheattributes.DiskUsagePatternName=UPDATE

##############################################################
##### AUXILIARY CACHES
# Indexed Disk Cache

Comment: jcs.auxiliary.DC=org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheFactory
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes=org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheAttributes
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.DiskPath=../scripts/calc/cache/indexed-disk-cache
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.MaxPurgatorySize=10000
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.MaxKeySize=10000
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.OptimizeAtRemoveCount=300000
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.OptimizeOnShutdown=true
jcs.auxiliary.DC.attributes.MaxRecycleBinSize=7500

Comment: Nope.It isnt doing any good.I dont know where I am making a mistake.Can u send me a sample snippet of your code.One that is working,sorry I cant help it,because I am completely new to this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5688/discussion-between-ademiban-and-madhu-sudhan)